# How to save place for images before page is loaded?

Tags: html, css

I have such problem with images in Chrome:

when page is loading firstly text appears, than text is moving, and finally images appearing.

I will show in screenshots ( if someone wants I can give you a link to site  )

Before images are loaded

[image]

after:

[image]

I have set sizes of images.

HTML:

```
 <img alt="I_01" height="66" src="http://91.228.126.168:3000/images/i_01.png" width="73">
```

and CSS(as you can see I'm using Bootstrap ):

```
  .second .span4 img {
  padding-right: 10px;
  float: left;
  }
```

**Questions: What I need to add to make them load properly ? What I should do to prevent images loading cause on performance ?**

Comment: @Sirwan, I don't understand what do you mean ? is it correct way ?

Comment: @Sirwan, can you give example in code ?

Comment: then make that image inside `div` and fix it's width...

Comment: have a link of CSS Sprite http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp and http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi now used to this image in background in your anchor link

as like this

**Css**

```
.textline{
display:inline-block;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:black;
  vertical-align:top;
  background:url('http://91.228.126.168:3000/images/i_01.png') no-repeat 0 0;
  padding-left:80px;
line-height:70px;
}
```

**HTml**

```
<a href="#" class="textline"> link Text</a>
```

***[Demo link](http://tinkerbin.com/cYsOVqb0)***

Comment: Thanks. What reccomendation you can give me for performance ?

Comment: @MID now you can used to background images in your anchor link i give u example in above ..........

Comment: Ok, what you can tell is CSS Sprite is better to use or not ?

Comment: @MID Css sprite is better and used to background-position throw css sprite  more info about this http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

Answer (score 1):

You need to preload images so that images are ready in cache before browser displays the images.

image preloading can  be done in javascript. you may follow the link below for the same.....

http://www.learn-javascript-tutorial.com/ImagesWindowsandTimers.cfm#Preloading-Images

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly specify width an height for images, then text won't move even if image is not loaded yet. Browser will immediately display empty images of specified size, and then load images.

Comment: @MID You have to specify dimensions, like `66px` instead of `66`. And it is better to specify them using CSS rule or at least `style` property, not with `width` and `height`

Comment: I used Rails Helpers to set sizes. Is it better for performance to use images as background ?

Comment: @MID I don't think there will be any noticeable difference in this case.

Comment: I have a lot of images) Less request, faster performance. Or I'm not right ?

Comment: @MID Yes, for a lot of images CSS sprites will be very useful.

Comment: one more thing - should I put all css i ONE file to make loads faster ?

Comment: @MID yes, putting CSS in one file also improves load times. There should be some libraries for combining CSS server-side. At least for ASP.NET there are a plenty of them.

Comment: As I know in RubyOnRails - assets pipeline should concatenate and minify JavaScript and CSS, but I see a lot of requests, so I think I will ask another question.